# Pulling a survey with multiple answers from a database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a working survey that pulls each question and any related answers from multiple tables. Each question is stored in the following table:

- tblQuestions, with the fields:
- qID
- qText.

The related answers are stored in the table:

- tblPossAnswers, with the fields:
- aID
- qID
- answerText.

So, I would have 3 possible answers for each question. My sql to pull everything is:

```
select * from tblQuestions, tblPossAnswers where
tblPossAnswers.qID = tblQuestions.qID
order by tblQuestions.qID ASC
```

And my PHP to display it:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

echo "<p>" . $row['qText'] . "</p><br />";
echo "<input type='radio' name='".$row['qID']."' value='".$row['aID']."' />";
echo $row['answerText'];
}
```

The problem is this is displaying the qText every time it displays a possible answer. So it looks like:

- Question 1
- Possible answer 1
- Question 1
- Possible answer 2
- Question 1
- Possible answer 3
- Question 2
- Possible answer 1
- Question 2
- Possible answer 2
- Question 2
- Possible answer 3

What I would like to do is have the qText only display when the first possible answer is pulled. I'm still somewhat of a newb to MySQL, so the solution might be something very simple that I'm just not seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either test for whether the question has changed within your PHP loop:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  if ($row['qID'] != $lastQuestionID) {
    echo "<p>" . $row['qText'] . "</p><br />";
    $lastQuestionID = $row['qID'];
  }
  echo "<input type='radio' name='".$row['qID']."' value='".$row['aID']."' />";
  echo $row['answerText'];
}
```

Or else you can group the MySQL results by question using [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), specifying a separator on which you then split the answers in PHP:

```
select *, group_concat(answerText separator char(30)) as answers
from tblQuestions join tblPossAnswers using (qID)
group by tblQuestions.qID
order by tblQuestions.qID ASC
```

Then:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<p>" . $row['qText'] . "</p><br />";
  foreach (explode(chr(30), $row['answers']) as $answer) {
    echo "<input type='radio' name='".$row['qID']."' value='".$answer."' />";
    echo $answer;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to change anything in sql just change php slightly as following

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  if ($row['qText'] != $lastQuestion) {
    echo "<p>" . $row['qText'] . "</p><br />";
    $lastQuestion = $row['qText'];
  }
  echo "<input type='radio' name='".$row['qID']."' value='".$row['aID']."' />".$row['answerText'];

}
```